# Anthurium misshapen leaves, brown marks and yellowing leaves

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, plant-health

My anthurium is not looking his best lately and I don't know what is wrong. I have repotted him somewhere in spring this year and he was doing great until a few months ago. I haven't changed anything in how I care for him (I don't use fertiliser).

The first trouble signs (1-2 months ago) were misshapen leaves and flower; they have an 'indent' (see arrows):

[image: indents]

Apart from that, everything seemed fine at the moment, so I didn't worry about it.

However, recently the new leaves were even more misshapen and have some brown dry marks on them:

[image: Misshapen leaf 1]
[image: Misshapen leaves]
[image: Curled misshapen leaf]
[image: Underside of misshapen leaf]

A few  days ago, some older leaves started to yellow:

[image: yellow leaves]
[image: yellowing leaf]

A flower which was developing also suddenly turned brown:

[image: Browning flower]

I scanned for bugs but I didn't see any on the plant itself. I did find four (pale, beige) mites on the cache-pot, but I don't know if they are to blame. The brown marks are also only on the new leaves and on *all* the new leaves.

Picture from above:

[image: from above]

Picture of the bottom of the pot:

[image: Roots]

**EDIT**

The fifth photo (from the original post) shows the underside of a leaf.

Below I added some more photos of undersides of leaves.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: And there is no sign of pests on the leaves?